# Cannot Catch com.mongodb.DuplicateKeyException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

There is a Index in db(mongo) if I try to save a data which is already present it throws an DuplicateKeyException but I cannot handle it using try catch.

Model Class

```
@Document("users")
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

createUser

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomUserDetailsManager implements UserDetailsManager {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userReposiotry;

    @Override
    public void createUser(UserDetails user) {
        try {
            User newUser = new User();
            newUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
            newUser.setPassword(user.getPassword());
            userReposiotry.save(newUser);
        } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
            log.error("username already exists");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

stackTrace

```
2022-03-23 19:47:37.884 ERROR 10852 --- \[nio-8080-exec-1\] o.a.c.c.C.\[.\[.\[/\].\[dispatcherServlet\]    : Servlet.service() for servlet \[dispatcherServlet\] in context with path \[\] threw exception \[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: Write operation error on server localhost:27017. Write error: WriteError{code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: playground.users index: username dup key: { username: "ahamed" }', details={}}.; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Write operation error on server localhost:27017. Write error: WriteError{code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: playground.users index: username dup key: { username: "ahamed" }', details={}}.\] with root cause
```

I want to handle that error and and send an appropriate response to client.

Comment: Have you imported correct ```DuplicateKeyException``` in your ```CustomUserDetailsManager``` class?

Comment: Turns out I imported a wrong DuplicateKeyException. I should have imported this org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException but I imported the other one com.mongodb.DuplicateKeyException .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why，But I got it from here

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException
```